# Rename files in R - delete character

Tags: r, character

I have multiple files to analyze that are now called "E - 04(fld 1 wv Red - Cy5)" ad I want to delete the 0 so that they become just "E - 4(fld 1 wv Red - Cy5)".
Is there a way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to Rui Barradas answer, you could use the package `stringr` and remove the zero from the name or names, by typing:

```
fileNames <- "E - 04(fld 1 wv Red - Cy5)"
stringr::str_remove(fileNames, '0')
[1] "E - 4(fld 1 wv Red - Cy5)"
```

Answer (score 0):

This base R [regex](https://regex101.com/r/gFQ67m/1) seems to do the job.

```
x <- "E - 04(fld 1 wv Red - Cy5)"
sub("(^[^[:digit:]]*)0([[:digit:]]+.*$)", "\\1\\2", x)
#[1] "E - 4(fld 1 wv Red - Cy5)"
```

If you want to change many filenames, maybe a function will make it easier to perform the task.

```
changeName <- function(x){
  sub("(^[^[:digit:]]*)0([[:digit:]]+.*$)", "\\1\\2", x)
}

x <- "E - 04(fld 1 wv Red - Cy5)"
changeName(x)
#[1] "E - 4(fld 1 wv Red - Cy5)"

y <- c("E - 04(fld 1 wv Red - Cy5)", "E - 06789(fld 1 wv Red - Cy5)")
#[1] "E - 4(fld 1 wv Red - Cy5)"    "E - 6789(fld 1 wv Red - Cy5)"
changeName(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use look arounds and str_remove:

```
> library(stringr)
> s
[1] "E - 04(fld 1 wv Red - Cy5)"
> str_remove(s, '(?<=E - )0(?=4\\(fld 1 wv Red - Cy5\\))')
[1] "E - 4(fld 1 wv Red - Cy5)"
>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `sub`

```
sub("0", "", str1)
#[1] "E - 4(fld 1 wv Red - Cy5)"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "E - 04(fld 1 wv Red - Cy5)"
```